# Android- What is the return key called?

Tags: android, keylistener, onkeylistener

I am currently creating a key listener that runs code when the enter key is pressed. It works on my actual pc keyboard when I run the enter key. The code looks something like this:

```
        inputtedMachineKey.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            // If the event is a key-down event on the "enter" button
            if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN &&
                    keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
                Toast.makeText(SelectMachineKeyActivity.this, "Enter Key Hit!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Problem is that KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER is only working for the enter button on an actual keyboard. For the emulated keyboard, when the return/enter key is pressed, nothing happens.

[image]

Does anyone know the keycode for the enter button for the image I posted?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

That should be keycode_enter / 66 (0x00000042)

see [List of keycodes](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent#KEYCODE_ENTER)

Comment: Just realized something... For some reason, the key listener does not recognize the keys inputted on the emulated keyboard (it only listens to the the keys typed on my actual keyboard)! I will do more research on this :)

Comment: @JasonChan I wonder how to recognize the keys inputted on the emulated keyboard too.